# How to get a list containing the values and the keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to understand what's the most efficient way for producing a list containing the values and the keys of a dictionary. I've tried using `.items()` function but with poor results because `items()` returns a list of tuples that then I have to flatten importing other modules. At the moment I am using:

```
zdict = { 'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
mylistofvaluesandkeys = list(zdict) + list(zdict.keys()))
```

The result I am looking is a list e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']` where I've all the elements in any order.

Is there a better way to perform this task?

Comment: The result you're looking for is `[1, 2, 3, a, b, c]` right?

Comment: What's the expected output? Do you need any specific order? For example, can can values and keys be mixed together?

Comment: A simple way to get the keys and values is to use the `* operator`, like so `result = [*zdict ,*zdict.values()]`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco they can mix up together. I would appreciate your answer even though now the question has been closed.

Comment: @NewPythonUser it seems a good option, I am sorry you could not post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do it lazily with `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.chain(zdict.values(), zdict.keys())
<itertools.chain object at 0x10a25a9d0>
>>> list(itertools.chain(zdict.values(), zdict.keys()))
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable to have keys mixed with values you can simply do this:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*zdict.items()))
```

This is the result:

```
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable(zdict.items())`…

Comment: @deceze `chain.from_iterable` is the preferred method when you're dealing with huge iterables. It allows you to not have all the elements available at the same time. I don't think this is the case though, because we're dealing with an in-memory dictionary. Thanks for your contribution btw, it can be useful in other cases :)